# destroy_user_session leads to a show action in Ruby with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes, haml

Apologies for the confusion in the title but its exactly what it sounds like.
I have a route generated by devise as destroy_administrator_session but every time I link to it, it takes me to a show method for that model which doesn't exist.

The model name is administrator and here is the route

```
destroy_administrator_session DELETE /administrators/sign_out(.:format)        devise/sessions#destroy
```

My Haml calls

```
= link_to('signout', destroy_administrator_session_path)
= link_to ('Logout', destroy_administrator_session_path), :method=>'delete'
= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_administrator_session_path, :method=>'delete'
```

Each one is written slightly differently but they all bring the application back to the show method of administrator which I have not implemented. As you can see from the devise route above, show is never touched.

Lastly is my routes.rb file

```
  get "/administrators/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_administrator_session
  devise_for :administrators
  resources :administrators
```

I have some hunches to what could be going on.

1. The routes are defined incorrectly
2. I need to specify what happens on the actual devise route and some more configuration is needed
3. My resources are clashing, however removing them does nothing.

Any help appreciated

Comment: You really don't want a logout method to be invoked by GET.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
devise_for :administrators do
  delete "/administrators/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_administrator_session
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Still have no idea what happened or why this made the change it did but hopefully It'll help someone along the way

```
  devise_scope :administrator do
    get "/administrators/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_administrator_session
    devise_for :administrators
  end
  resources :administrators
```